# asp.net controls not able to grab the value or text

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a cleEditor on my page which needs rows="" cols="" and asp.net does not like this when I do runat="Server"

To get around this I was trying to use FindControl, but I cannot seem to grab the value this way.

Here is my code:

```
protected void os_submit_Click ( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    Control cleEditor = FindControl( "editor2" );
    MailMessage mm = new MailMessage( "OnlineSignup@help.com", "help@help.com" );
    mm.Subject = "Online Signup Checklist";
    mm.Body = cleEditor.value; // Trying to grab the value of the textarea
    mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.Host = "127.0.0.1";
    smtp.Port = 25;
    smtp.Send( mm );
}
```

I have a TextArea that has the id of editor2.  Behind the scense jquery turns this into a rich text editor.  I need asp.net to be able to grab the value/text of this textarea.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Without the runat="server" attribute, you cannot access the control in the code-behind, period.

Comment: whoever posted the answer and then deleted it, post it again since it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't put `runat="server"` on the TextArea and do this:

```
protected void os_submit_Click ( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    MailMessage mm = new MailMessage( "OnlineSignup@help.com", "help@help.com" );
    mm.Subject = "Online Signup Checklist";
    mm.Body = Request.Form["editor2"]; // Trying to grab the value of the textarea
    mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.Host = "127.0.0.1";
    smtp.Port = 25;
    smtp.Send( mm );
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry not sure why I didn't think of that.  now I am getting the nasty `A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (editor2="<b>testing</b>      ...").` error.  I even added ValidateRequest="false" and it is still giving the error weird.

Comment: did you try adding <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" /> to web.config ? What version of .NET are you using? Are you using ASP.NET or ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Yeah, I added all of that and it seems to have fixed the issue.  ASP.NET 4.0.  Thanks again for the answer. :)